# Android intent-filter for urls in general?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an app that should respond to the ACTION_SEND sharing intent but preferably only when an url is shared. I can't filter on mimetype alone because text/plain is used for a lot of content (although urls are the most common?)

I thought I could use

```
<data android:scheme="http" />
```

but after testing it with Chrome (sharing a page) it turned out that doesn't work. If I log the output of intent.getDataString() it returns null so I guess I can't use `<data>` at all?

My question in short:
If a user shares a webpage or url from for example Chrome, my app should be present in the "Share to" dialog. If it is a textfile it should not.

For completeness, here is my current filter in manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".ActShareUrl" android:label="Sharedr: shorten url">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Note: Since I can't find the answer online on my own I think I'm searching for/with the wrong keywords so if anyone can point me to an existing answer I'll update the title of this question if needed.

Comment: "If a user shares a webpage or url from for example Chrome, my app should be present in the "Share to" dialog. If it is a textfile it should not." -- AFAIK, there is no way to accomplish that. You are certainly welcome to run some tests and see what MIME types are used by popular browsers, but my guess is that it will be `text/plain`. Your `<data android:scheme="http" />` approach does not work because that only looks at the `Uri` in the `Intent` (`getData()`), not `Uri` values that may be stuffed in extras.

Comment: Thanks for the insight concerning the data object and that the url is actually included as an extra.. It's obvious but easily overlooked (as I sort of did). I'll look into it some more and try some different approaches, let's see if we can figure this out :)

Comment: @REJH any success on this? I'm trying a similar thing but did not find a solution so far.

Comment: Nope. It seems it can't be done :(